# Numpy create an array of matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to store matrices into an array, however when I append the matrix, it would get every element and output just an 1 dimensional array.

Example Code:

```
matrix_array= np.array([])
for y in y_label:
      matrix_array= np.append(matrix_array, np.identity(3))
```

Comment: Are you looking for a 3D array or a list/vector of your matrices? Also, why not just have `matrix_array.append(np.identity(3))` inside of your for loop?

Comment: I am looking for a 3d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly `np.append` is the wrong tool for the job:

```
In [144]: np.append(np.array([]), np.identity(3))
Out[144]: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
```

From its docs:

> If `axis` is not specified, `values` can be any shape and will be
>       flattened before use.

With list append

```
In [153]: alist=[]
In [154]: for y in [1,2]:
     ...:     alist.append(np.identity(3))
     ...:    
In [155]: alist
Out[155]: 
[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]), array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])]
In [156]: np.array(alist)
Out[156]: 
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]])
In [157]: _.shape
Out[157]: (2, 3, 3)
```